# Digital certificates for embedded systems

Tags: security, https, cryptography, embedded

I an responsible for deploying a large amount of embedded devices and want to add https.

I've done a bit of googling and am a little confused as to where exactly my plan falls through.

1. Get a certificate signed by a reputable CA
2. Use the corresponding private key to sign new certs for each device
3. User connects to device (e.g.192.168.1.40) and receives 2 certificates
4. User's browser verifies that the device's cert. was issued by my company
5. User's browser verifies that my companies cert. was issued by reputable CA

Can someone please poke a few holes in that??

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196728/advanced-ssl-intermediate-certificate-authority-and-deploying-embedded-boxes)

Comment: I was under the impression that most commercial CAs did not deliver certificates with the CA bit set, which is required if you want to use the certificate as a CA to sign downstream certificates. Otherwise everyone would only ever need to buy one certificate and generate all the rest they need!

Comment: On the other hand, you don't need a CA's certificate if you just connect to your own server. You just need a secure way of installing your own root certificate in the embedded's device's truststore(s). The you can create certificates all you want. Try a CA based on "openssl" or EJBCA for instance, but readup on PKI before you do, and keep those private keys safe.

Comment: And while you do your reading, I'll vote to close as it is not related to programming, I'll try and flag you to be transferred to servervault...